# How to write a Task wrapper type? (The return type of an async method must be a task-like type)

Tags: c#, async-await

Consider the following sample code

```cs
    public static class TestClass
    { 
        static async TaskWrapper<int> Test()
        {
            var task = Task.FromResult(4);
            return await new TaskWrapper<int>(task);
        }
    }

    public class TaskWrapper<T>
    {
        private readonly Task<T> _thing;

        public TaskAwaiter<T> GetAwaiter() => _thing.GetAwaiter();

        public TaskWrapper(Task<T> thing)
        {
            _thing = thing;
        }
    }
```

The compiler reports the following error on the `Test()` function: `error CS1983: The return type of an async method must be void, Task, Task<T>, a task-like type, IAsyncEnumerable<T>, or IAsyncEnumerator<T>`.

Why is this the case? The TaskWrapper type implements the GetAwaiter() method by deferring to the wrapped task type. As a matter of fact, the following test function compiles just fine, demonstrating that `TaskWrapper` is indeed awaitable:

```cs
        static async Task Test()
        {
            var task = Task.FromResult(4);
            _ = await new TaskWrapper<int>(task);
        }
```

Comment: The error message seems perfectly clear to me. See duplicate for explanation. What that has to do with your `TaskWrapper<T>` type is unclear; the error message pertains _specifically_ to method declarations that use the `async` keyword. That doesn't mean there aren't other "awaitable" constructs in the language. There's no inconsistency with respect to the error message.

Comment: I love the fact that someone closed this question because it's allegedly answered in another question - which itself was closed for supposedly being too vague to be answered. (Feels like an xkcd cartoon waiting to be written) More relevantly, the other question didn't involve a "task-like type". This one clearly does. So what exactly is a task-like type? I would like to know the answer too. But you're not going to get an answer here obviously. Maybe try https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang.

Comment: If you are just trying to create an awaitable see Stephen Toubs blog https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-anything/

Comment: TLDR; awaitable != task like. You can await your TaskWrapper because `GetAwaiter()` complies with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#awaitable-expressions. A task like type must have a builder so the compiler / runtime can construct your task and return it.

Comment: Tasklikes are extremely rare, especially now that we have `ValueTask<T>`. What exactly are you trying to **do** with `TaskWrapper<T>`?

Comment: @StephenCleary I actually was trying to use it to mitigate the cumbersome generic type parameter inference of the C# compiler in my APIs. It's a little to involved to go into detail, but I simply wanted a custom type with custom members that behaves like (and inherits from) Task.

Comment: @StephenCleary Btw, since my wrapper type was going to have more than 1 type parameter it seems that this workaround won't work for my particular case: apparently the async method builders can have at most 1 generic type parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from C# 7.2, the compiler supports task-like types. A *task type* is a class or struct with an associated *builder type*, identified with the [`AsyncMethodBuilderAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.asyncmethodbuilderattribute). Example:

```
[AsyncMethodBuilder(typeof(TaskWrapperMethodBuilder<>))]
public class TaskWrapper<T>
{
    //...
}
```

The *builder type* is a class or struct that corresponds to the specific *task type*. The *builder type* should have the following public methods:

```
class TaskWrapperMethodBuilder<T>
{
    public static TaskWrapperMethodBuilder<T> Create();

    public void Start<TStateMachine>(ref TStateMachine stateMachine)
        where TStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine;

    public void SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine);
    public void SetException(Exception exception);
    public void SetResult(T result);

    public void AwaitOnCompleted<TAwaiter, TStateMachine>(
        ref TAwaiter awaiter, ref TStateMachine stateMachine)
        where TAwaiter : INotifyCompletion
        where TStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine;

    public void AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted<TAwaiter, TStateMachine>(
        ref TAwaiter awaiter, ref TStateMachine stateMachine)
        where TAwaiter : ICriticalNotifyCompletion
        where TStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine;

    public TaskWrapper<T> Task { get; }
}
```

With this infrastructure in place, you can then write asynchronous methods that return the `TaskWrapper<T>` type.

Reference:
[Extending the async methods in C# - Task-like types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/extending-the-async-methods-in-c/#task-like-types)
[Async Task Types in C#](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/task-types.md)

And here is an actual implementation of a task-like type, that does [something useful](https://github.com/mgravell/PooledAwait):
[PooledTaskT.cs](https://github.com/mgravell/PooledAwait/blob/master/src/PooledAwait/PooledTaskT.cs)
[PooledTaskMethodBuilderT.cs](https://github.com/mgravell/PooledAwait/blob/master/src/PooledAwait/MethodBuilders/PooledTaskMethodBuilderT.cs)

Comment: Since I'm just looking to defer to the Task type and not implement some custom state machine, is there a way to point to the method builder of Task?

Comment: @Chiel without being absolutely sure, I don't think that you can get away with not implementing a dedicated `MethodBuilder` type, even if your custom task-like type inherits directly from the `Task<T>` class.

Answer (score -1):

An async method must return a `Task`. If you want to return something else, find a way to avoid marking the method async. For example, this should work:

```
public static class TestClass
{ 
    static TaskWrapper<int> Test()
    {
        var task = Task.FromResult(4);
        return new TaskWrapper<int>(task);
    }
}
```

Comment: "An async method must return a Task" - nope, it can return a *task-like* type, such as `ValueTask`. This was a new feature in C# 7. It's a relatively involved process - see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/extending-the-async-methods-in-c/ for example. But it's definitely possible.